# Show UILabel with complete text or hide it

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have a UI label say "ABCDEFGH". In iPhone 6 etc wider devices I can show the complete text. In small screen devices like iPhone 5, I see text as "ABCD...". I want the following:

```
if(complete text can be shown) 
{
    // show UILabel with text
} else // if text can not fit in, "ABCD..." case 
{    
    // hide the UILabel
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why didn't you tried to fit the text rather than hiding? try this adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

Comment: I don't want to change the font. Case is there are two words, "Main Event". I want to show just "Event" if whole text cannot fit in. So I have two UILabels, "Main" and "Event". High priority is given to word "Event" and low priority to "Main". 

I will show "Event", no matter what. And check if "Main" can be shown completely, if not I want to hide it. So if I use adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth, font of "Main" will change and it will look bad. For the user it's like a single UILabel

Answer (score 1):

call the `sizeToFit` function on the `UILabel`. If it's size is longer that the maximum, hide it...

Comment: How do I check if size is longer than maximum? I mean I will have to set some max width or find max required width.

Comment: If you are using autolayout, the label will init with the max width. save the initial width and test if after sizeToFit it is longer...

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned in comment to use `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES` but it seems to be not good fit for your scenario. I will suggest you to check the screen sizes and set `UILabel` according to that.

```
CGSize deviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

if(deviceScreenSize.height == 480){     //iPhone 4,4s Screen Size
// Write your code for UILabel Here.
}
if(deviceScreenSize.height == 568){    //iPhone 5,5s Screen Size
// Write your code for UILabel Here.
}
if(deviceScreenSize.height == 667){   //iPhone 6 Screen Size
// Write your code for UILabel Here.
}
if(deviceScreenSize.height == 736){  //iPhone 6s Screen Size
// Write your code for UILabel Here.
}
```

There might be some better way to do so.But i know this one only.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Screen's size like this :

```
CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
```

And then put an if statement like this :

```
if (label.frame.size.width>screenSize.width) { 
        //Use smaller label }
else {
        //use bigger label }
```